# How can I get the charset of oracle database dump?

Tags: database, oracle, character-encoding, export

C:\Wex\DB_Runtime>imp AUTH_OWNER/AUTH_OWNER FULL=y IGNORE=y FILE=AUTH_OWNER.dmp

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Sep 22 18:42:07 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

Comment: I am having dump file only, and not sure what is the charset for it. So while importing I am getting error IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle .

Comment: Ist that a datapump export (created by expdp)?

Comment: Checkout the below error similar to your post. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63741/importing-a-different-character-set-export-dump-into-another-db-instance